# coldfusion act_download.cfm 404 erros in logs - from my own IP?

Tags: coldfusion

My site runs in Coldfusion. I'm seeing a few 404 errors in my logs for '`.../act_download.cfm`' - I thought might be a hack attempt but the ip is my local ip. Maybe I have a virus?

I've googled for it and can't find anything helpful but what is interesting is lots of uk local government sites (those types of sites are often written in coldfusion) seem to have '`act_download.cfm`' in some of their pages..

Does anyone know what '`act_download.cfm`' is?

Comment: Sounds like a model file being used by a framework that all these .gov.uk sites have in common, for serving up download files.

Comment: It means somewhere in your code you're relocating to that URL, but there is nothing @ that URL. Same as any 404... except you're doing it to yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your replies Adam and Duncan - I've searched my code base for any instance of 'act_download.cfm' but alas nothing found - still a mystery.. Thanks very much for replying though.

Comment: PS Can anyone enlighten me as why my question has been down voted to -2? What am I doing wrong? Thanks :)

Answer (score -4):

Definitely an attempt at a server hack.

It is your web server reporting the 404 because that particular file does not exist. You see it is the web server that passes any .cfm/.cfml file to ColdFusion - if it does not exist web server serves the default 404 (not found). If the template DID exist - well - not a security risk.